# Properties of natural logarithm

Tags: logarithms

$\ln( n + 1 ) - \ln( n ) > \frac 1{n+1}$

Is this statement true?
I tried  to show by $$\ln( n+1 /n)\implies  
1+ 1/n > 0,    
\quad n >1$$
That is all I could get to so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Method**

Let $f(x)=\ln(x+1)-\ln x-\frac{1}{1+x}$.
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}=\frac{x(x+1)-(x+1)^2+x}{x(x+1)^2}=...<0$$
for all $x>0$ and thus $f$ is strictly decreasing on $]0,+\infty [$. Moreover,
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+ }f(x)=+\infty $$
and $$\lim_{x\to+\infty }f(x)=0$$
Therefore, $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$.

**Second Method**

$$(n+1)\left(\ln(n+1)-\ln n\right)=\ln\left(\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n+1}\right)=\ln\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right).$$

You have that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty }\ln\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)=\ln(e)=1.$$

Moreover, $x\mapsto \ln x$ is increasing and thus, if you set $$x_n=(n+1)\left(\ln(n+1)-\ln(n)\right)=\ln\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right),$$ $(x_n)$ is decreasing. Indeed, it's easy to show that $$y_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}$$
is decreasing, and thus that $x_n=\ln(y_n)$ is also decreasing. Therefore $x_n>1$ for all $n$ and thus 
$$(n+1)\left(\ln(n+1)-\ln n\right)>1\implies \ln(n+1)-\ln n>\frac{1}{n+1}$$
what conclude the proof.

Comment: Nice method of approach , do you also know other methods?because I like to see on different angles

Comment: I wrote an other method and my previous answer.

Comment: Excellent method if I had the " rep " to vote I would have!

Comment: no problem, I'm happy to have helped you :-)

Answer (score 0):

here is another way to look at this $$\ln(n + 1) -\ln n = \ln \frac{n+1}{n} = \ln \left( 1 + \frac 1 n\right) = \int_1^{1 + \frac  1n} \frac{dx}{x} < \frac 1 n  \frac 1{\left(1 + \frac 1 n\right)} = \frac 1{n+1}$$

the reason for the inequality is that the function $\frac 1 x$ is decreasing on the interval $1 \le x \le 1 + \frac 1n.$

Comment: How is integral of 1/x from 1 to 1+1/n less than 1/n(1/1+1/n). I could not understand this part.

Comment: @Socre, the function $1/x$ is decreasing on $[1, 1+\frac 1 n].$